# How to use cbreak mode in Ruby terminal application?

Tags: ruby, input

In a small Ruby application, I'd like user input to be accepted without having to wait for a carriage return. My understanding is that cbreak mode needs to be enabled in order for the terminal to feed user input directly into the script.

I tried simply running x%[cbreak()] at the top of my script but that didn't work. I've also seen that it's possible to use (n)curses to achieve the same results, although that seems like overkill.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution which avoids having to use curses (which I find difficult to implement) is to use the shell's `read` command via `%x`. It doesn't feel right dipping into the shell to do something that seems like Ruby's STDIN should be responsible for, but it's simple and it works.

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

puts "Please enter your first initial"

str = %x[read -s -n1 keypress; echo $keypress]

puts "Your first inital is " + str
```

Answer (score 1):

`cbreak` is a curses function call, so `%x` definitely doesn't apply (that is for executing shell commands).  `cbreak` is defined in the standard curses library, so that would probably be your best bet.

See:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/curses/rdoc/classes/Curses.html#M000280

**Edit**: you might also check out `Curses.getch`

Comment: I had misunderstood cbreak by thinking it was a bash command. Thanks for clarifying.